# Mapping composition in Java

Tags: java, mathematics, composition

(See also [the continuation of this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287026/mapping-composition-in-java-v2).)

This time, I have a mapping type:

**`com.github.coderodde.mapping.Mapping.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.mapping;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements a mapping from a domain set to a range set.
 * 
 * @param <D> the domain element type.
 * @param <R> the range element type.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 3, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 3, 2023)
 */
public final class Mapping<D, R> {

    final Map<D, R> data = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void map(D domainValue, R rangeValue) {
        checkDomainValueNotYetMapped(domainValue);
        data.put(domainValue, rangeValue);
    }
    
    public boolean isMapped(D domainValue) {
        return data.containsKey(
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        domainValue,
                        "The input domain value is null."));
    }
    
    public R map(D domainValue) {
        checkDomainValueIsMapped(domainValue);
        return data.get(domainValue);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        
        boolean first = true;
        
        for (Map.Entry<D, R> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            
            sb.append("(")
              .append(entry.getKey())
              .append(", ")
              .append(entry.getValue())
              .append(")");
        }
        
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    private void checkDomainValueNotYetMapped(D domainValue) {
        if (data.containsKey(
                Objects.requireNonNull(domainValue, "Domain value is null."))) {
            throw new DuplicateDomainValueException(
                    "Trying to map a domain value ["
                            + domainValue
                            + "] twice.");
        }
    }
    
    private void checkDomainValueIsMapped(D domainValue) {
        if (!data.containsKey(domainValue)) {
            throw new DomainValueIsNotMappedException(
                    "Domain value [" + domainValue + "] is not mapped.");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I can compose mappings:

**`com.github.coderodde.mapping.MappingComposition.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.mapping;

import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class provides facilities for composing mappings.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 3, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 3, 2023)
 */
public final class MappingComposition {
    
    /**
     * Composes two functions together. For example, if 
     * {@code mapping1 = [(1, 'a'], (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]} and 
     * {@code mapping2 = [('a', "Alice"), ('c', "Clarice")]}, then the composed
     * mapping is {@code [(1, "Alice"), (3, "Clarice")]}.
     * 
     * @param <D> the domain value type of the first mapping.
     * @param <T> the domain value type of the second mapping. This is the same
     *            as the range value type of the first mapping.
     * @param <R> the range value type of the second mapping.
     * @param mapping1 the first mapping.
     * @param mapping2 the second mapping.
     * @return a composed function.
     */
    public static <D, T, R> Mapping<D, R> compose(Mapping<D, T> mapping1, 
                                                  Mapping<T, R> mapping2) {
        Mapping<D, R> result = new Mapping<>();
        
        for (Map.Entry<D, T> entry1 : mapping1.data.entrySet()) {
            D domainValue = entry1.getKey();
            T temporaryValue = entry1.getValue();
            
            if (mapping2.isMapped(temporaryValue)) {
                R rangeValue = mapping2.map(temporaryValue);
                result.map(domainValue, rangeValue);
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

... I need some exception definitions:

```
package com.github.coderodde.mapping;

/**
 * Instances of this class are thrown on occasions where the domain value is not
 * yet mapped to a range value.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 3, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 3, 2023)
 */
public final class DomainValueIsNotMappedException extends RuntimeException {
    
    public DomainValueIsNotMappedException(String exceptionMessage) {
        super(exceptionMessage);
    }
}
```

```
package com.github.coderodde.mapping;

/**
 * Instances of this class are thrown on occasions where the domain value is 
 * already mapped and we are trying to map it to a second range value.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 3, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 3, 2023)
 */
public final class DuplicateDomainValueException extends RuntimeException {
    
    public DuplicateDomainValueException(String exceptionMessage) {
        super(exceptionMessage);
    }
}
```

Finally, the demonstration program follows:

```
package com.github.coderodde.mapping;

class MappingCompositionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mapDual();
        mapFour();
    }
    
    private static void mapDual() {
        Mapping<Character, Integer> mapping1 = new Mapping<>();
        Mapping<Integer, String> mapping2 = new Mapping<>();
        
        mapping1.map('a', 1);
        mapping1.map('b', 2);
        mapping1.map('c', 3);
        
        mapping2.map(1, "Alice");
        mapping2.map(2, "Clarice");
        
        System.out.println(MappingComposition.compose(mapping1, mapping2));
    }
    
    private static void mapFour() {
        Mapping<Character, Integer> mapping1 = new Mapping<>();
        Mapping<Integer, String> mapping2 = new Mapping<>();
        Mapping<String, Long> mapping3 = new Mapping<>();
        Mapping<Long, Float> mapping4 = new Mapping<>();
        
        mapping1.map('a', 1);
        mapping1.map('b', 2);
        mapping1.map('c', 3);
        
        mapping2.map(1, "Alice");
        mapping2.map(3, "Clarice");
        
        mapping3.map("Alice", 11L);
        mapping3.map("Bob", 12L);
        mapping3.map("Clarice", 13L);
        
        mapping4.map(11L, 11.0f);
        mapping4.map(12L, 12.0f);
        mapping4.map(13L, 13.0f);
        
        System.out.println(
                MappingComposition.compose(
                        MappingComposition.compose(mapping1, mapping2),
                        MappingComposition.compose(mapping3, mapping4)));
    }
}
```

**Demo output**

```
[(a, Alice), (b, Clarice)]
[(a, 11.0), (c, 13.0)]
```

**Critique request**

As always, I would like to hear whatever comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Mapping`'s `domainValue` method's parameters represent keys in `data` map might worth calling them differently closer to their purpose. Probably they are called `domainValue` since while calling the methods values of other `Mapping`s are passed in.

With exceptions interrupting the flow the `MappingCompositionDemo` is an example of either all succeed either all fail, if this isn't the intended behaviour the code gets cluttered with try/catch blocks when other scenarios are implemented.

`Mapping#toString` method's complexity could be improved by appending separator string `,`  after each `entry` string and deleting the last separator string occurrence before other further appends.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("[");
        
    for (Map.Entry<D, R> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            
        sb.append("(")
          .append(entry.getKey())
          .append(", ")
          .append(entry.getValue())
          .append("), ");
    }

    sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());

    sb.append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that we prohibit `null` in the domain, but allow it in the range. This is by no means a bad thing (assuming it's intentional - and the use of explicit `containsKey` checks rather than checking the return values of `Map.putIfAbsent` and `Map.get` for `null` seems to suggest that it is), though it may require some attention - for example, it seems like the `compose` method will throw a `NullPointerException` if `mapping1` maps any value to `null`, since it passes each value in `mapping1`'s range to `mapping2.isMapped`, which in turn passes its argument to `Objects.requireNonNull`

I also note that `toString` manually implements the string joining, rather than using one of the standard library's existing `String`-joining utilities. We might be able to simplify that method using `String.join`, or perhaps using a `Stream` that gets collected by `Collectors.joining`

Finally, I'm not convinced we need distinct exception types for this. It seems like there are existing, well-known exception types which can communicate what is going on just as clearly (especially with an informative exception message). `IllegalStateException` (for attempted double mappings) and `NoSuchElementException` (for undefined lookups) come to mind