# Mapping composition in Java - v2

Tags: java, mathematics, composition

This post is the continuation of [Mapping composition in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286837/mapping-composition-in-java).

This time, I:

1. Disallowed the `null` values as the range value.
2. Simplified the `toString` method via using the streams.

**Code**

**`com.github.coderodde.mapping.Mapping.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.mapping;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * This class implements a mapping from a domain set to a range set.
 * 
 * @param <D> the domain element type.
 * @param <R> the range element type.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.61 (Sep 14, 2023)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 3, 2023)
 */
public final class Mapping<D, R> {

    final Map<D, R> data = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void map(D domainValue, R rangeValue) {
        checkDomainValueNotYetMapped(domainValue);
        Objects.requireNonNull(rangeValue,
                               "The range value is not allowed to be nul..");
        
        data.put(domainValue, rangeValue);
    }
    
    public boolean isMapped(D domainValue) {
        return data.containsKey(
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        domainValue,
                        "The input domain value is null."));
    }
    
    public R map(D domainValue) {
        checkDomainValueIsMapped(domainValue);
        return data.get(domainValue);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .map(Mapping::convertMapEntryToString)
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
    }
    
    private static <D, R> 
        String convertMapEntryToString(Map.Entry<D, R> entry) {
        return new StringBuilder()
                    .append("(")
                    .append(entry.getKey())
                    .append(" -> ")
                    .append(entry.getValue())
                    .append(")").toString();
    }
    
    private void checkDomainValueNotYetMapped(D domainValue) {
        if (data.containsKey(
                Objects.requireNonNull(domainValue, "Domain value is null."))) {
            throw new DuplicateDomainValueException(
                    "Trying to map a domain value ["
                            + domainValue
                            + "] twice.");
        }
    }
    
    private void checkDomainValueIsMapped(D domainValue) {
        if (!data.containsKey(domainValue)) {
            throw new DomainValueIsNotMappedException(
                    "Domain value [" + domainValue + "] is not mapped.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

As always, please tell me whatever comes to mind.

Comment: Why dont you use the adapter pattern? Could you fix spotbugs, PMD and checkstyle issues? Are you signing the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Mapping** class seems unnecessary, as your `compose` function shown in the previous post could just use **Map** types, which are already defined in a standard way within Java. all you're really doing is wrapping the methods of the inner `data` instance variable which is a map.

Comment: True. However, note that rolling my own wrapping class gives me — at the very least— control over the way a map is converted to a string.

Comment: Yeah and that could be extracted out into a separate function that takes a map as input and then you wouldn’t have to convert existing maps into **Mapping** to use your new functionality

Comment: I think it’d be cool to have `compose` be a variadic function

Comment: Not quite sure how to write variadic functions. Wanna elaborate your answer?